# Resizing the JQPlot chart issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

I want to resize a Jqplot chart based on the orientation. I have the below code. Its not working.

```
    var plot = $.jqplot('chartDivId', dataArray, options);
        var w = parseInt($(".jqplot-yaxis").width(), 10) + parseInt($("#chartDivId").widt(), 10);
        var h = parseInt($(".jqplot-title").height(), 10) + parseInt($(".jqplot-xaxis").height(), 10) + 
    parseInt($("#chartDivId").height(), 10);
        $("#chartDivId").width(w).height(h);
        plot.replot();

        $(window).on("orientationchange",function(event){
      alert("Orientation is: " + event.orientation);
        plot.replot( { resetAxes: true } );
    });
```

It will work if comment out the below code

```
   /*    var w = parseInt($(".jqplot-yaxis").width(), 10) + parseInt($("#chartDivId").width(), 10);
         var h = parseInt($(".jqplot-title").height(), 10) + parseInt($(".jqplot-xaxis").height(), 10) + parseInt($("#chartDivId").height(), 10);
         $("#chartDivId").width(w).height(h);
         plot.replot();
   */
```

I don't want to comment out the above code, how do i solve the problem ?

Thanks..Johnson

Comment: Can somebody pls answer my question ?

Comment: Hi @Johnson Tummalapalli, did the post below help you?

Comment: Hello Anish, I was busy and didn't had a chance to check it. I will check & confirm. Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Change in orientation results in change in the size of the div/container/window.
So you can achieve it using the `resize` event of jQuery.

So the code to do that would be as follows.

```
$(window).on("resize",function(event){
    plot.destroy(); // Destroy the chart..
    plot.replot(); // Replot the chart with new/old values..
});
```

Check out the working fiddle here: [jqPlot Line Chart - Replot on resize event](http://jsfiddle.net/anish_nair/jcvLktyh/1/)

If you are not able to see the output(chart) in Google Chrome, please try a different browser instead.

If it didn't help, would like you to update your snippet with some more code.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hello Anish, Its still not working. The below code is the culprit. But I don't want to comment it out.

var w = parseInt($(".jqplot-yaxis").width(), 10) + parseInt($("#chartDivId").width(), 10);
         var h = parseInt($(".jqplot-title").height(), 10) + parseInt($(".jqplot-xaxis").height(), 10) + parseInt($("#chartDivId").height(), 10);
         $("#chartDivId").width(w).height(h);
         plot.replot();